# Sensor readings from sensor not stored in order in the firebase real-time database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, esp8266

I'm trying to send the sensor readings to the firebase realtime database. it's working fine but the problem that suddenly the data not stored in order. For example, as shown below.. the data of hour 10 stored below hour 1 instead of complete storing below hour 9. (bounded with *** for clarification purposes)

```
    "2021-2-9 0:30:0" : "Open",
    ***"2021-2-9 10:0:0" : "Closed",***
    ***"2021-2-9 10:30:0" : "Closed",***
    "2021-2-9 1:0:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 1:30:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 2:0:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 2:30:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 3:0:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 3:30:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 4:0:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 4:30:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 5:0:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 5:30:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 6:0:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 6:30:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 7:0:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 7:30:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 8:0:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 8:30:0" : "Open",
    "2021-2-9 9:0:0" : "Open",
    ***"2021-2-9 9:30:0" : "Open"***
```

I used DS1302 and ESP8266 and the following libraries :

#include "FirebaseESP8266.h"

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#include <virtuabotixRTC.h>

#include<time.h>

#include <TimeLib.h>

#include <NTPClient.h>

#include <WiFiUdp.h>

Is it normal?
Please help!
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is because it's sorted as a string.

If your data is 1, 2, 3, 10, it will be ordered 1, 10, 2, 3 because the string 10, comes before the string of 2

So change how the data is stored; either as a Timestamp, convert to double or it must be a string use yyyymmddhhmmss

So this "2021-2-9 10:0:0" would be

```
20210209100000
```

and would sort after this "2021-2-9 1:30:0"

```
20210209013000
```

Also, use 24 hour time format.

Comment: thanks for replying! I could you please share a sample code?

Comment: @HAN Sure - what kind of sample code would you like? It's just a matter of either storing your strings as something that's 'sort friendly' as shown, or as a timestamp or convert it to a double for storage and back to a human readable string when read back in.